# ViewPager иногда отказывается пролистывать свайпом фрагменты

Tags: android, android-viewpager

У меня имеется `ViewPager` на 3 вкладки, каждая вкладка это фрагмент. Каждый  фрагмент реализован на основе `LoaderManager` для обновления информации во фрагменте в реальном времени из БД. Собственно вопрос:  Иногда фрагменты пролистываются свайпом влево-вправо, а иногда свайпну раз 10, а он ни в какую не реагирует. Я честно говоря даже не знаю в какую сторону думать.

Comment: У меня такая проблема когда тулбар скроллится, попробуйте на эмуляторе кнопками вправо-влево переключать, и посмотрите, будет ли проблема

Comment: @McDaggen да, переключение по названию вкладок как по маслу, и  я вот сколько с проблемой этой встречаюсь, тоже порой возникает ощущение, что пока тулбар полностью не открыт/закрыт свайп будет глючить